# Appengine Shared Memcache not storing data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Appengine Shared Memcache in Java. All of a sudden it stopped storing and its not even throwing any exception. My implementation is as follows,

```
   public class MemcachedUtil 
   {

           public static final int ONE_DAY_SECONDS=86400;
           public static final int ONE_DAY_MILLISECONDS=86400000;
           public static final int ONE_HOUR_SECONDS=3600;
           public static final int ONE_HOUR_MILLISECONDS=3600000;

         public static void set(String key,Object value,String namespace)
        {
    MemcacheService srv=MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService(namespace);
    srv.put(key,value, Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(ONE_DAY_SECONDS)); 
         }
             ............ // Get / GetAll / Set methods like above.... declared.
   }


     In another class , i am implementing like follows....
...
     MemcachedUtil.set("salePrice_"+highToLow+"_"+pageNo, retVal, "Test"); // Set
     MemcachedUtil.get("salePrice_"+highToLow+"_"+pageNo, "Test"); // Get
```

and given expiration times as follows,

```
    public static final int ONE_DAY_SECONDS=86400;
    public static final int ONE_DAY_MILLISECONDS=86400000;
    public static final int ONE_HOUR_SECONDS=3600;
    public static final int ONE_HOUR_MILLISECONDS=3600000;
```

Any one aware of why this? Even I have updated , Appengine SDK 1.9.0 and tried dedicated memcache too. Nothing works. But still , not even get clue why is that all of a sudden?. Kindly help me out to figure out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be srv.set() and srv.get()?

Comment: My class "MemcachedUtil" contains all set , get methods collectively. Edited my qn , kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your source code has not changed, but the version of the runtime libraries has changed, suggests that the old runtime libraries were able to serialize your retVal Object and the new runtime libraries are silently failing to do that, resulting in nulls.  Try altering the type of what you are submitting to the cache, for example by converting to a String before set and converting the String back to your object after get.  It requires some effort, sure, but you won't find a silver bullet for this problem if you use Object.

Comment: Thank you Martin, Lemme try.